# Unable to download the file from Ionic InAppBrowser App

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking, inappbrowser

I have a href link on clciking the download icon the PWA is able to download the file, but the apk that is created is not able to download the file. Can someone help me with this issue?

I am using Deeplinking as well.
[Deeplink Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlKct.png)

Comment: check for storage permission.

Comment: Can you send me Screenshot of the code please?

Comment: Hi @NajamUsSaqid 

I have pr45ovided the permission as well but of no use here.